# Matlab loop to convert N x 1 matrix to 60 x 4718 matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am a novice at Matlab and am struggling a bit with creating a loop that will a convert a 283080 x 2 matrix - column 1 lists all stockID numbers (each repeated 60 times) and column 2 contains all lagged monthly returns (60 observations for each stock) into a 60 x 4718 matrix with a column for each stockID and its corresponding lagged returns falling in 60 rows underneath each ID number.

My aim is to then try to calculate a variance-covariance matrix of the returns.

I believe I need a loop because I will be repeating this process over 70 times as I have multiple data sets in this same current format

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: are the entries sorted by stockID or are they shuffled?

Comment: Take a look at `reshape` and `permute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `data` denote your matrix. Then:

```
aux = sortrows(data,1); %// sort rows according to value in column 1
result = reshape(aux(:,2),60,[]); %// reshape second column as desired
```

If you need to insert the stockID values as headings (first row of result), add this as a last line:

```
result = [ unique(aux(:,1)).'; result ];
```

A simple example, replacing 60 by 2:

```
>> data = [1   100
           2   200
           1   101
           2   201
           4    55
           3     0
           3    33
           4    56];
>> aux = sortrows(data,1);
>> result = reshape(aux(:,2),2,[])
>> result = [ unique(aux(:,1)).'; result ];

result =

     1     2     3     4
   100   200     0    55
   101   201    33    56
```

Comment: I would add `stockID = unique(data(:,1))` to have a vector of stock IDs corresponding to each column

Comment: I was just about to do that, thanks! But I think it has to be `unique(aux(:,1))` to match order, right?

Comment: yes right, although it doesn't matter. `unique` returns sorted values by default.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, that works fantastically! You saved me here!!

Comment: @user3196098: Please consider accepting the answer =) It is the tick on the left side of the answer.